# Node view, reference User and Profile2 fields

Tags: entities, views

I am trying to accomplish the following.

I have a node view that shows fields based on the nid contextual filter.
This I use mainly for formatting purposes.

I then added a content pane where I want to show User AND Profile2 fields that reference the node being viewed.

When adding a relation ship to the profile, this does not seem to work..

Is there a clean way to do this, or do i need to create a separate user view for this?

The general idea is to show all users that reference this node in a content pane.

Thanks so much for all suggestions!

Comment: how are the users related to the node(s)? are they the author? is there a field with a user name or uid? or a field in the user profile with nid information?

Comment: Dear geoff, the node references to the user through an entity reference field called 'profile' on the node.